# Visual Studio 2015 git show all branches

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to make the Visual Studio 2015 history window display all branches?

By default it displays the branches like this:

[image]

I want it to display like this:

[image]

Notice how the image above displays my latest commit on `dev/test2` even though I didn't merge it into `master`

My current Source Control plug-in is set to `Git`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have experienced, Visual Studio is showing the history for the currently checked out branch, afaik that is by design, to prevent it working through too many commits.  It only show earlier branches if they are merged back into the currently checked out branch. 
But as you see SourceTree have no issues with this.
And I fully agree with you that showing the historyof all should be - at least - an option.
There is a [Uservoice suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8374770-view-history-for-whole-git-repository) for this, which really need more support.  Vote it up!

Comment: Too bad the voting is closed now. :(

Comment: @Andrew Not closed, just moved: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365478/view-history-for-whole-git-repository.html Also see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/382989/show-combined-git-branch-history-including-common.html

Comment: Update 2022-10: All mentioned aboved "closed - DUPLICATE", but this one is currently open: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-do-i-view-the-history-of-all-branches-in-git/934801

Comment: Since Visual Studio 2022 *still* does not have this, one workaround is to use Visual Studio *Code* with the GitGraph extension. It does a beautiful job of showing the combined Git branch histories. See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph